# How to convert xml to json on nodejs app

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js

I have gone thru this article http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/ which explains it clearly how to do conversion but for some reason it is not working on me.

Let me share the code with you:

```
   function parseXml(xml) {
    var dom = null;
    if (window.DOMParser) {
      try {
        dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
      }
      catch (e) { dom = null; }
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
        dom = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        dom.async = false;
        if (!dom.loadXML(xml)) // parse error ..

          window.alert(dom.parseError.reason + dom.parseError.srcText);
      }
      catch (e) { dom = null; }
    }
    else
      alert("cannot parse xml string!");
    return dom;
  }
```

and this is the sample of trying to convert to json:

```
var xml = '<e name="value">text</e>',
          dom = parseXml(xml),
          json = xml2json(dom);
```

I get an error saying "window is not defined". Well, for sure I do not have window here initiallised, I just dont know how should I do with it, since I am inside nodejs app.

and the xml2json you can see from the article as it is too long to post here...

Any suggestion, would appreciate....

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're accessing the `window` object to get the DOMParser or Microsoft.XMLDom ActiveX object.  This code was intended for use in a browser, with all the concerns required to conform to different browser types, etc.

Because you're in `nodejs`, you can greatly simplify this.  First, you need something that can parse XML into an `XMLDom`-like object.  There are several - I've not used any, but a quick google found [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom).  There are others out there, so have a look around and see what you feel is right for you and your project.

Once you've got that installed into your project, code like the following (**Untested**) should work:

```
function parseXml(xml) {
  var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
  try {
    return new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
  }
  catch (e) { 
    return null; 
  }
}
```

This will give a DOMParsed-equivalent that can then be read through `json2xml`.